# Does disconnecting from TCP socket after sending message guarantees deliver?

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

I couldn't find much information on this, but I have a simple sequence of code like:

```
// does it wait on Write() until successful handshake or attempt failure
// or just continue on straight away?
net.conn.Write(buffer[1:60])
conn.Close()
```

Does this guarantee delivery to client/server before `Close` is called? Or will Close be called after the message sent, and potentially close the connection during the handshakes if they were too slow to complete in time ?

Comment: Maybe you can be clearer about what you mean by guarantee. TCP tries its best to deliver messages but if there is a network problem it can't solve that.

Comment: I guess it depends on implementation, but at least in standard cases, closing a socket (after the connection has been established) should make a best attempt to deliver the data in the buffers first.

Comment: @JamesKPolk i mean will the code still be on Write() and not go to Close() until the handshake has completed or failed ? Or does it write/send and then just run Close() regardless of the result of it, meaning it could close when it hasn't yet finished the acknowledgement from the client ?

Comment: @Radu thats good to know that it tries to send the buffers, do you know where they have that mentioned any where in writing though ?

Comment: `Write()` is a blocking call and it return the number of `bytes` it has written and an optional `error` if any, [more info here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.Write)

Comment: It's not that easy to find something in writing, because it differs on the OS, programming language, how you set up your sockets, etc. You can find some info about how MS implements it in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k(v=vs.110).aspx Other languages and OSes can do it differently.

Comment: You are supposed to call the socket's Shutdown method before you close it. This should "flush" any pending data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this guarantee delivery to client/server before `Close` is called?

No.

> Or will `Close` be called after the message sent

Both the write and the close are queued for asynchronous execution.

> and potentially close the connection during the handshakes if they were too slow to complete in time?

`Close` will queue a close for the connection. If the close handshake takes too long the connection will be reset.

Comment: So whats the safe way of handling this situation where you want to close but need to know if the message successfully sent or "successfully" failed to send so you know to close the connection or try send again first?

Comment: The peer application has to tell you.

Comment: `Write` at least is a blocking call, not async. I don't know about `Close` but somehow I doubt its async, since every I/O call I know of in Go is blocking; Go makes everything synchronous and leaves it up to you to run it async in a goroutine if you choose to do so. It's possible under certain operating systems, the OS will run it async without the process having a say in the matter, but it's certainly not universally true.

Comment: This is not explicitly stated in the documentation, however, it is strongly implied by the explanation of how timeouts work; `Write` and `Read` both *return an error* if the write/read times out; this would be impossible if they were writing/reading asynchronously.

Comment: @Adrian 1. `write()` equals `send()`, which *operates* asynchronously, due to the presence of the socket send buffer. Same for `close(()`, and this remains true whether you know about it or not: otherwise there is no reason for SO_LINGER with a positive timeout to  exist. I do suggest you look this up. 2. I didn't say anything about reads working asynchronously. 3. There is no 'explanation of how timeouts work' that says that writes return an error if *this* write times out.

Comment: It doesn't matter how send operates, Go's Write will not return until the write is completed.  Your comment about timeouts doesn't make any sense - you set a deadline, and any subsequent operation (depending on which deadline you set) will return an error if it doesn't complete before that deadline.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing can "guarantee delivery" (what if the other end of the connection just crashed?). However, `Write` is a blocking call, and if you check the returned `error` value, you can at least know whether or not the write succeeded before you call `Close`.

Comment: You can know whether the write succeeded in transferring your data to the socket send buffer. Nothing more.